# The function call inside sizeof doesn't invoke it? C++

Tags: c++, function, linker, sizeof

Consider this code, I am trying to print the sizeof return value of the function:

```
int f(int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(f(2)) << std::endl;
}
```

This surprisingly (for me at least) prints 4.

But should this give me a link error as the function is not defined?
Are functions inside sizoef not invoked? Is there a broader rule for expressions inside sizeof?

Comment: [Unevaluated_expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

> When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the expression
> [...]

More on unevaluated expressions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions)

Comment: Just to fill this out a bit, calling `f(2)` returns `int`, so `sizeof(f(2))` gives the size of `int`. +1.